# Почему id не изменяется

Tags: python

```py
str = "Hello"
id (str)
4353682096
str = "hai"
id (str)
4353682096
str = "Hello"
id (str)
4353682096
```

Почему при переназначении строки с 'hai' на 'Hello' ее id остается таким же как и при первой инициализации?

[image: Screen]

Comment: когда я переопределяю строку старое значение  же должно исчезнуть
и уже присваивать другое id даже есть текст тот же

Comment: Стопудов, в интерактивной консоли вводили, ну там где `>> `. Она довольно ленивая, поэтому когда вы переписывали ссылку на строку в переменной, предыдущий объект строки переиспользовался. Выполните этот же код в полноценном скрипте и увидите что на каждый `str = ` создается новый объект с другим id. Кст, питон оптимизирует небольшие строки, поэтому для одинаковых строк будет тот же id. Больше инфы: https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-strings-can-be-tricky-sometimes-

Comment: У меня меняется. Покажите скриншот?

Comment: Да, скорее всего питон оптимизирует

Comment: Ну вот на вашем скриншоте всё тоже отлично меняется. У строки `"Hello"` один id, у строки `"hai"` другой id. Строк в коде всего две (одинаковые действительно оптимизируются), вот и получилось два разных id

Comment: Теперь понял
Спасибо